# What does "control of a deformation problem" mean?

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, deformation-theory, definitions

Is the expression "control of a deformation problem' ever defined? There are of course many examples relating a dg-Lie or L-infty algebra to a deformation problem, and the phrase is evocative. Is it ever defined?